# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin(\log(n))\cdot \frac{1}{n^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the range of values $p$ such that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \sin(\log(n))\cdot \frac{1}{n^p}$$ converges.

Context: this question was on an undergraduate real analysis exam at a university in China.

My intuition is that it should converge for $p>1$ and diverge for $p<0,$ just based on the alternating series test, but I am not sure about the values in the middle.

How would one go about establishing the convergence of such a sum?

Comment: $n^i=\cos \log n + i \sin \log n$ is a starting point.

Comment: It is a real alternating series? Because $\sin(\log n)$ may be positive or negative in fact.

Comment: @i707107 To go where?

Comment: OP: Is Dirichlet's test in your bag of tools?

Comment: @Did affirmative